# org.openqa.selenium.UnhandledAlertException in chrome and IE

Tags: java, selenium, alert

I have an alert box with a certain number generated. (I need the number)
I wrote the following code in JAVA:

```
try{
    Alert myalert=driver.switchTo().alert();
    String txt=myAlert.getText();
    myAlert.accept();
}
catch(UnhandledAlertException e){}
catch(Exception e){}
```

I have also tried setting browser capability to `IGNORE,ACCEPT,DISMISS`

None of them worked and I still get `UnhandledAlert Exception Model` dialogue present exception and Selenium script fails.

How can I fix this?

Comment: can you give the URL of the site which trows the alert?

Comment: it is a client URl , i am afraid i can't share it

Comment: Then its really hard to help you. If you feel afraid to share here, you can share me to santhosh12992@gmail.com

Comment: Can you share the exception trace?